# Symfony2 404 on 1 page of symfony in production

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

We have got 1 page out of 50 in symfony that will not work and comes up with a 404 error message. We beleive it has something to do with the .htaccess but below is some more information with the .htaccess at the very bottom.

When checking this i've checked the twig file which has the following path

```
path('_webhosting')
```

I've done console routes:debug which shows the _webhosting route and i've checked the controller to make sure everything looks okay, which it does.

Now the strange this is when we go to the prod.log file it shows the following error:

```
request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:
"No route found for "GET hosting.html" (from "https://www.xyz.com/")"
at /home/xyz/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1977
{"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException: 
No route found for \"GET hosting.html\" (from \"https://www.xyz.com/\") at
/home/xyz/public_html/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1977,
Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException: 
at /home/xyz/public_html/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:320)"} []
```

This seems to be showing that it is looking for hosting.html which as we are on a shared hosting we've had to put a htaccess file in to redirect to the web folder. We can't seem to find anything that would cause it to strip the /web but this is the file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Did you clear the cache (Symfony and APC)? Can you run `app/console routes:debug --env=prod`?

Comment: @Touki yes the routes:debug shows the _webhosting route inside this with all 3 columns set to ANY, I have cleared the cache using cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug and APC is inbuilt into php 5.5 so i haven't go direct access to this i don't believe. Also i've never changed the route name which is why we are lead to believe it is the htaccess

Comment: @Touki actually i've just realised APC isn't actually installed. So it can't be that

Comment: So the intended path of your route is '/hosting.html'?

Comment: @phpisuber01 no the intended path is _webhosting which is webhosting.html changing the route to hosting.html in the twig and the routes.yml to resolve to hosting.html worked but we was wanting webhosting.html so we beleive it is an issue with the htaccess file removing the web part of the file